# Getting data from cells in SlickGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slickgrid

What method do I use for SlickGrid to get the cell contents? For example:

```
...
grid = new Slick.Grid($("#myGrid"), data, columns, options);
grid.onAddNewRow = function(item,colDef) {
  grid.removeRow(data.length);
  data.push(item);
  grid.updateRowCount();
  grid.render();
}

grid.onCurrentCellChanged = function(args){
  // get cell content!
};
...
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The grid is modifying your data source directly, so the changes will be applied to "data".
The "onCurrentCellChanged" event is fired when the user changes the active/selected cell, and gets {row:currentRow, cell:currentCell} as a parameter.  To get to the cell data, you can use `data[args.row][grid.getColumns()[args.cell].field]`, assuming you are using the column.field to access the data and not a custom formatter that gets the data in some other way.

Comment: No, I'm not using a custom formatter, so this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank Tin!

Answer (score 2):

`grid.onCurrentCellChanged` seems to have changed to `grid.onActiveCellChanged.subscribe` in 2.0

Comment: Looks like onActiveCellChanged occurs when the user focuses on a different cell for editing. For changes in the value of the data in the cell, you want grid.onCellChange.subscribe.