# How do I return a specific cell value in SlickGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

For the life of me I can't seem to return a specific cell value in SlickGrid.  There is an example on SO [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210120/getting-data-from-cells-in-slickgrid) But this did not work either.  I am using the SlickGrid tutorial #7 as my example.  All I am trying to do is add a click event to a cell that returns that cells value.

Note: I am loading my data via JSON request and all works well.  My click event fires but the value is undefined.  For brevity sake I will omit my grid columns and options code.  Here is the code and thanks.  All and all this is a great grid.

```
var sortcol = "id";
    var sortdir = -1;
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON(baseURL() + 'programs', function (data) {
            dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();
            grid = new Slick.Grid($("#program-grid"), data, programColumns, programOptions);

            grid.onSort = function (sortCol, sortAsc) {
                sortdir = sortAsc ? 1 : -1;
                sortcol = sortCol.field;

                if (sortAsc == true) {
                    data.sort(compare);
                }
                else {
                    data.reverse(compare);
                }
                grid.render();
            };
            grid.onClick = function (e, row, cell) {
                if (programColumns[cell].id == "id") {
                    var x = data[row][cell].field;//This is where I am stuck
                    window.location.href = "http://google.com/" + x;
                }
            }

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there, you should use data[row].fieldname. Do you have a field in your data called "field"?

Comment: I tried that as well and I still get undefined.  Whats funny is that when I debug in firebug the row and column index numbers are correct. Just no value.

Comment: Update I figured out what the problem was.  My JSON object properties come over the wire with camel case names (FirstName, LastName, etc.) SlickGrid has an "id" field that (by all accounts) is usually used to identity the field you want.  Like my example "if(programColumns[cell].id == "id")" refers to the SlickGrid id field that I labeled for SlickGrid as id but came over the wire as Id.  So in a nutshell "data[row].NameAndCaseOfFieldAsItAppearsOverWire" is correct.  Thanks for your help Jason. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you're using dataView, it's simple:

```
// Get the object containing row and cell index of a clicked row.
var gridObject = roundGrid.getCellFromEvent(e); 

var row = gridObject.row; // get selected row index
var row_values = roundDataView.getItem(row); // get the row object 

// Get the actual value.
var cellValue = row_values[roundGrid.getColumns()[gridObject.cell].field];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Bind to the onCellChange event**

```
grid.onCellChange.subscribe( function( e, args ) {

    console.log( args.item[ grid.getColumns()[ args.cell ].field ] );

} );
```

**Returns**

"{some value}" etc. *"This is the newly changed value"*

**Docs**

onCellChange `({ row: number, cell: number, item: any })`

[Grid Events (onCellChange)](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Grid-Events)