# SlickGrid row attribute syntax?

Tags: object, syntax, slickgrid

<rant>I'm getting downright frustrated with the <strike>lack</strike> absence of documentation for SlickGrid.</rant>

Sorry -- now that that's out of my system . . .

I'm trying to figure out the correct syntax for returning a value in a cell in a row.  For example, let's say I have the following data:

```
ID   Object      Color
1    This        Red
2    That        White
3    OtherThing  Blue
```

I want to do something similar to this (I'll use the onMoveRows event as an example):

```
grid.onMoveRows = function (rows, insertBefore) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        if (rows[i].Color == "Blue") {
            // do something
            }
    }
};
```

The **rows[i].Color == "Blue"** is my issue.  I don't know the proper syntax for this (or even if this is possible), I can't find it documented anywhere, and I don't want to waste my time trying to figure it out (I've already spent a couple of hours trying to do so).

Can someone clue me in?

Thanks in advance . . .

Comment: Think my ignorance of JavaScript might be showing (too used to VBScript).  Looking into JavaScript array objects . . .

Comment: I found what I was looking for [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769286/how-do-i-return-a-specific-cell-value-in-slickgrid).

Answer (score 1):

'rows' is an array of row numbers that are being moved.
For example, if you selected rows 1,2 and 5, the 'rows' will contain [0,1,4] (it's 0-based).

Comment: That's helpful.  I thought "rows" was an object array containing row data.  I wasn't aware that it was just a number array.  That's why I was having trouble with it.